# AWS DocumentDB compatibility with Ruby on Rails And Angular JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Hi I would like to know if AWS Document DB, is compatible with Ruby on Rails, AngularJS and Express JS?

Currently I have two apps that use Mongo DB (Ruby on Rails and the other Angular / Express JS) and I would like to know if the frameworks support AWS DocumentDB

https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Amazon DocumentDB implements the MongoDB 3.6 API. Any framework that has a MongoDB 3.6 connector should be able to talk to DocumentDB. Things like [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) should be able to open a connection with no changes. There is a [complete list of the supported operations and data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) in the documentation. As long as your apps don't rely on any operations or commands not contained in this list, it'll run just as it does on MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try : )

Comment: How did it go with your tests?

Comment: Hi @bwest, The test is in progress. So far it works on my Node JS app and mongoose. Thank you! : ) However I am still working on connecting from a development environment. I posted a new question at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153452/how-to-connect-to-aws-documentdb-via-ssh-tunnel-in-node-js-app